# How to print positions of grid lines?

Tags: labeling, geotools

I am using geotools, my goal is to print locations (of grid) in normal way.

How to  prepare style in a correct way?

```
 public Style createLineStyle2() {
        StyleBuilder sb = new StyleBuilder();
        FilterFactory ff
                = CommonFactoryFinder.getFilterFactory(GeoTools.getDefaultHints());

        Font font = new StyleBuilder().createFont("Verdana", 12.0D);
        Font fonts[] = {font};

        AnchorPoint anchorPoint = sb.createAnchorPoint(0.5, 0.5);

        PointPlacement pointPlacement = sb.createPointPlacement(anchorPoint, null, sb.literalExpression(0));
        LinePlacement linePlacement = sb.createLinePlacement(0.0);
        TextSymbolizer text = sb.createTextSymbolizer(null, fonts, sb.createHalo(),
                sb.attributeExpression("Location"), pointPlacement, "Location");


        Style style = sb.createStyle();
        LineSymbolizer lineSymbolizer = sb.createLineSymbolizer(Color.red, 1.0);
        Rule rules[] = {sb.createRule(text), sb.createRule(lineSymbolizer)};
        FeatureTypeStyle fts = sb.createFeatureTypeStyle("Feature", rules);
        style.featureTypeStyles().add(fts);

        return style;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please clarify what do you mean by normal way?

Comment: I would like to print latitude and longitude of grid line crosses.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be this line:

```
TextSymbolizer text = sb.createTextSymbolizer(null, fonts, sb.createHalo(),
   sb.attributeExpression("Location"), pointPlacement, "Location");
```

Where you use `Location` for the text but I suspect it is your geometry.

I use code like this as I have a label attribute with the text I require, see this [blog post](http://blog.ianturton.com/geotools/mapping/cartography/2015/06/17/fun-with-graticules.html) for a longer discussion of how I create the grid and the labels:

```
style = SLD.createSimpleStyle(featureSource.getSchema());
Style red = SLD.createLineStyle(Color.red, 1.0f);
((LineSymbolizer)red.featureTypeStyles().get(0).rules()
    .get(0).symbolizers().get(0)).getStroke().setOpacity(ff.literal(0.5));
layer = new FeatureLayer(featureSource, style);
layer.getBounds().getCoordinateReferenceSystem();
ReferencedEnvelope gridBounds = layer.getBounds();


StyleBuilder sb = new StyleBuilder();
java.awt.Font font = java.awt.Font.decode("Arial");
TextSymbolizer text = sb.createTextSymbolizer(Color.red,
   sb.createFont(font), "label");

LabelPlacement lp = sb.createLinePlacement(ff.literal(4));
text.setLabelPlacement(lp);
red.featureTypeStyles().get(0).rules().get(0).symbolizers()
   .add(text);
gridLayer = GridUtilities.createLabeledGridLayer(red, gridBounds,
    xwilkinson);
```

to produce this map:

[image]

Alternatively you could try something like this untested code to extract the X or Y coordinate of the line:

```
Expression expression = ff.function("if_then_else", 
        ff.function("equalTo", ff.function("endAngle", ff.property("Location")),ff.literal(0.0)),
        ff.function("getX", ff.function("centroid", ff.property("Location"))),
        ff.function("getY", ff.function("centroid", ff.property("Location"))));
  text = sb.createTextSymbolizer(null, fonts, sb.createHalo(),
        expression, pointPlacement, "Location");
```

Comment: Almost fine with Expression 
http://pl.tinypic.com/r/206k32r/9

Comment: have a look at http://blog.ianturton.com/geotools/mapping/cartography/2015/06/17/fun-with-graticules.html for a discussion on how to construct the grid

Comment: `private void createGridLayer3(ListFeatureCollection fc, ReferencedEnvelope gridBounds) {
        OrthoLineBuilder lineBuilder = new OrthoLineBuilder(gridBounds);
        List<OrthoLineDef> orthoLineDefColl = new ArrayList<>();
        orthoLineDefColl.add(new OrthoLineDef(LineOrientation.HORIZONTAL, 1, 1.0));
        orthoLineDefColl.add(new OrthoLineDef(LineOrientation.VERTICAL, 0, 0.5));
        lineBuilder.buildGrid(orthoLineDefColl, new OrthoLineFeatureBuilder(gridBounds.getCoordinateReferenceSystem()), 10.0, fc);
    }`

How to add lablels in to setAttributes() method? @iant♦

Comment: Output with createGridLayer3() method :
http://pl.tinypic.com/r/bhy9gl/9